# Signout / Logout RealVNC Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, vnc

Is it possible to LogOut or SignOut of RealVNC Server on  Debian 10 System?

I have installed REalVNC with the the wrong credentials (UserNAme and Password) and when I remove and re-install RealVNC it is already logged in and there is not an option logout option available on the user interface.

I have removed REalVNC using instructions at https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002250957-Completely-Removing-VNC-Connect and when I re-install it is already logged in to an account, the wrong account, I need to have the REALVNC server into give me the option to logout and login in to a different account.

Do I have to re-install Debian to washout REalVNC???

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

**sudo apt purge realvnc-vnc-server (Debian and Ubuntu)**

**sudo yum purge realvnc-vnc-server (RedHat and CentOS)**

*"purge"* works a little bit different from *"remove"* and actually cleans up config files and other stuff

and also you can delete */home/user/.vnc* folder

It had worked for me. Good luck!